# How to drop all requests using mod_security

Tags: apache-2.2, security, web-server, mod-security

I have an apache2 server with several sites enabled on it, including the default one (000default). The default server is catching lots of spammy requests that are doing nothing but consume bandwidth and fill up the log file.

What would be a minimal virtual host config that would drop all requests that hit the default site?

This is what I have so far using mod_security, but it seems to do nothing but respond with a 403 for all requests:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName default.only
    SecRuleEngine On
    SecAction "drop,phase:1"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Try `SecRuleEngine off` for other vhosts?

Comment: thanks, but that didn't seem to make any difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to fix this with the following config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName default.only

    SecRuleEngine On
    SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "^\d" drop,phase:1
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks, this appears to fix the problem for requests on port 80 but not not 443. If I add analogous virtual host with 443 I get an error on my SSL enabled sites: "Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG". Is it possible to apply this to 443 as well?

Answer (score 5):

The `mod_security` action `deny` will produce a 403 response whereas `drop` will immediately close the connection.  [From the manual](http://www.modsecurity.org/documentation/modsecurity-apache/2.1.0/html-multipage/07-actions.html#N11041):

## drop

**Description:** Immediately initiate a "connection close" action to tear down the TCP connection by sending a FIN packet.

**Action Group:** Disruptive

**Example:** The following example initiates an IP collection for tracking Basic Authentication attempts. If the client goes over the threshold of more than 25 attempts in 2 minutes, it will DROP subsequent connections.

```
SecAction initcol:ip=%{REMOTE_ADDR},nolog
SecRule ARGS:login "!^$" \
    nolog,phase:1,setvar:ip.auth_attempt=+1,deprecatevar:ip.auth_attempt=20/120
SecRule IP:AUTH_ATTEMPT "@gt 25" \
    log,drop,phase:1,msg:'Possible Brute Force Attack"
```

**Note**

This action is extremely useful when responding to both Brute Force and Denial of Service attacks in that, in both cases, you want to minimize both the network bandwidth and the data returned to the client. This action causes error message to appear in the log "(9)Bad file descriptor: core_output_filter: writing data to the network"

Answer (score 4):

Apache has to handle the request in some way, it can't just ignore them. Responding with `403 Forbidden` is as close as you get.

Comment: You *can* drop connections without handling them using the mod_security module. It's the configuration of that module I'm having problems with.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me with libapache2-mod-security2 v2.8.0:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName 1.2.3.4

  CustomLog /dev/null combined

  # https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual
  SecRuleEngine On
  SecAction id:1,phase:1,nolog,drop
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixes the problem for requests on port 80 but not 443. If I add analogous virtual host with 443 I get an error on my SSL enabled sites: "Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG". Is it possible to apply this to 443 as well?